# Unable to represent an array of nested object input type using graphq-request

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma-graphql

I have been using graphql-request library as my GraphQL client choice, and from the first impression, everything was straightforward, until I started sending a nested array of objects whereby representing the data schema with GraphQL Document variables. Normally with apollo, you could define the data schema and types before your queries and mutations, but I am not sure how to do that with graphql-request library.

The actual data looks like this

```
const contacts = [
  {
    recordID: '4B6987A1-4179-426A-B38A-8B122995D0F8:ABPerson',
    givenName: 'test',
    phoneNumbers: [
      {
        label: 'mobile',
        number: '123456789',
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

Mutation looks like this

```
const TEST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation TestMutation($contacts: /* how to define the type of the data here???*/) {
    testMutation(contacts: $contacts) {
      recordID,
      givenName,
      phoneNumbers {
        label,
        number
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

If this question seems confusing to you, is there a way that a graphql-request library can define input types and got types like apollo?

Answer (score 0):

Both `apollo-client` and `graphql-request` are GraphQL clients that make standard GraphQL request -- your query would be the same regardless of what client you use (or if you made the requests using `fetch`, `curl` or some other means).

The variable `$contacts` is being used as the value of the `contacts` argument on the field `testMutation`, so its type must match that argument's type. In other words, whatever the type of the `contacts` is will need to be the type of the `$contacts` variable. What type is exactly depends entirely on the schema of the endpoint you're sending your query to. You can find that out by examining the schema or referencing the API's documentation. If you also coded the server, then you should already know the type.

Comment: first of all thanks for your response, let me put this in a different way. if you actually want to pass let's say one type we can do something like `$contacts: String!` but when we are defining the type of a nested data, I would like to do something like `$contacts: Contacts!` where type Contacts is defined beforehand. like this:
 type Mobile {
    label: String
    number: String
  }

  type Contacts {
    recordID: String!
    givenName: String
    phoneNumbers: [Mobile!]!
  }

Comment: On the backend, when creating your schema, you use [input object types](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Input-Objects) to represent complex input values. You would define an input object type and assign the type of the `contacts` argument to that type.

Comment: If this is the core of your question, you should rewrite your post because that's a backend-specific question that has nothing to do with `graphql-request`.